# python scrap data from .aspx web page

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to scarp the table from this webpage to pandas table:
https://www.perfectgame.org/College/CollegePlayerReports.aspx

I've used both requests and request-HTML but both don't seem to be effective,

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from requests import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

def get_stats( name, year ) :

    with HTMLSession() as s :
        source = 'https://www.perfectgame.org/College/CollegePlayerReports.aspx'
        response = s.get( source )
        table = response.html.find('table.Grid', first=True)
        df = pd.read_html( table.html, header = 0 ) [ 0 ]
        print( df )
```

any solutions?

Comment: You may wanna try selenium for this job, it's the appropriate tool in this context.

Comment: Still not working for me though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get data from table into pandas dataframe you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.perfectgame.org/College/CollegePlayerReports.aspx"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

data = []
for row in soup.select("tbody tr.rgRow, tbody tr.rgAltRow"):
    data.append(row.get_text(strip=True, separator="|").split("|"))

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    columns=["Reports", "Draft Eligible", "Class", "College", "Report Date"],
)
print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| Reports | Draft Eligible | Class | College | Report Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Drew Williamson | 2022 | Senior | Alabama | 6/1/2022 |
| Caden Rose | 2023 | Sophomore | Alabama | 6/1/2022 |
| Wyatt Langford | 2023 | Sophomore | Florida | 6/1/2022 |
| Nick Ficarrotta | 2022 | Freshman | Florida | 6/1/2022 |
| Fisher Jameson | 2024 | Freshman | Florida | 6/1/2022 |

...

Comment: It works... kinda, umm it only gets me half of the data? It's giving me odd number rows. But still thanks for the answer.

Comment: @sleepfreak Should be fixed now.

Comment: Can this solution read everything in the dataset? Right now it's only reading one page.